# "PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:" In flask application

Tags: apache, flask, python-3.6, mod-wsgi, permission-denied

Problem:
I'm getting the following error

> "PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
> '/home/[user]/daily_events_20200722.txt'

from this line of code:

```
with open(settings.HOME_PATH + f'daily_events_{time.strftime("%Y%m%d")}.txt', 'a') as fileobject:
```

What I've tried:
This is the fourth "location" I've tried.  The others I tried were the directory where the **init**.py file is and the parent of that directory (e.g. /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/ and /var/www/FlaskApp/), my "home" directory, and /tmp.

I should mention, here, that configuring the app to write to the /tmp directory eliminated the permission error, but no file gets written.  There is no error, the code continues on its merry way through that section of my code as if it wrote the file, and then errors in a different place (unrelated error) further down.

> UPDATE:  I think the answer to why no file gets written to /tmp is
> that apache2 redirects the output, as described here:
> https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167835/where-apaches-tmp-located,
> so I'm going to abandon writing to /tmp as a solution and concentrate
> on the permissions problem.
>
> It would be SO helpful if I could understand what credentials apache2
> and my flask app would be using when it tries to write the files.

I've also fiddled with the ownership and permissions (chmod) for all three of the attempted directories (e.g. user:rwx, group:r-x, others:r-x originally, but tried others:rwx.  Also tried root and  [user] as owner (chown) on all the mentioned directories and their parents).

I've also tried changing the FlaskApp.conf file in /etc/apache2/sites-available/ from:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName [serverip]
    ServerAdmin admin@[mydomain].com
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp.wsgi
    <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    Alias /static /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static
    <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

to:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName [serverip]
    ServerAdmin admin@[mydomain].com
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp.wsgi
    <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/[user]/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    Alias /static /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static
    <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

What research have I done:
I got most of the ideas for things to try (as described above) from searches here (Stack Overflow) on the error cited above.

Conventions:
I have substituted generic words inside brackets (e.g. "[stuff]") for actual entries in my production app config files, etc., just for the sake of not revealing too much info in a public forum like this one.

I'm using Python 3.6.9, a freshly installed mod-wsgi and apache2 (assuming latest versions) running on top of a fully updated Ubuntu Server 18.04, all on a Lightsaber instance at AWS.

What I want:
In general, elp fixing the problem so my FlaskApp can write the file somewhere. Specifically,I think it would be helpful to know what "user" credentials flask apps run under.  If I knew that, I might be able to figure out how to configure permissions for some place to write the file.  What's confusing to me is why the file isn't getting written to /tmp, which makes me think this issue may be more complex than a "permissions" error.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The user running Apache2 will need permission to write to the file whose path you're constructing. You can verify that by trying `/tmp`, which is world-writeable.

```
daily_events_path = '/tmp/test_daily_events.txt'
with open(daily_events_path, 'a') as fileobj:
    ...
```

If that works, either your prior fiddling with protections wasn't correct, or there's a gremlin like SELinux involved, in which case they may be a log entry in some obscure place in `/var/log` that provides a hint.

Comment: /tmp works.  I think I'm going to just let it go there since it doesn't really matter where as long as I can check it .  I'm going to have to remember /tmp in the future.  I didn't realize that was universally writeable.  The weird thing (and I forgot to put this in the original question) is that I am also writing data to a sqlite3 file and moving that to the '/home/[user]/' directory fixed a writeability problem with it.  Anyway...  Thanks!

Comment: I guess I spoke to soon.  writing to /tmp avoids the error, but no file actually gets written there.  I'm not sure if that's an effect related to writing 'anything' to /tmp or if I now have a new problem.  :-(

Comment: fileobject.write(json.dumps(data) + "\n")

And that is the end of the "with."  The next line is blank followed by an outdented "logging.info()," which, strangely, is also not getting written to /tmp where it's supposed to go as specified by this line earlier in the code:
    logging.basicConfig(filename='/tmp/FlaskApp.log',
                        format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s:%(message)s',
                        level=getattr(logging, 'INFO'))

Comment: What OS (and version) are you running this on?

Comment: Kernel = 5.3.0-1030-aws GNU/Linux,
Distro = Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Server,
On a Lightsail instance at AWS

Comment: @'Dave W. Smith' - I've made some updates to this and wonder if you have seen them.

Comment: @JohnCroc I'm hoping that someone with Lightsail experience can chime in. In your position, lacking that, I'd try writing to several places using a try/except block with logging in each section.

Comment: Thank you , Dave.  I am grateful for your help and will keep trying.